# AWS Cognito and React New Password Flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a React app that uses AWS Cognito with `aws-sdk` and `amazon-cognito-identity-js` to implement user managment.

I am stuck in the forget password flow, and I want it to go as follows:

1. The users enter his email, then I check if the email exists and send him a verification code if it does:

```js
  const handleEmailSubmit = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setFormDataErrors({});
        const email = _.get(formData, 'email', ''); // formData is the form state
        if(!email) {
            setFormDataErrors({ email: 'Email is required' });
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }
        const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
        const params = {
            UserPoolId: userpool.getUserPoolId(),
            Username: email,
        };
        try{
            await cognito.adminGetUser(params).promise();
        } catch(e) {
            const error = e as AWS.AWSError;
            if(error.code === 'UserNotFoundException') {
                setFormDataErrors({ email: 'Email not found' });
                setLoading(false);
                return;
            }
        }
        const user = new CognitoUser({
            Username: email,
            Pool: userpool,
        });

        user.forgotPassword({
            onSuccess: (_data) => {
                setCognitoUser(user);
                setStep(1);
            },
            onFailure: (_err) => {
                setFormDataErrors({ email: 'Something went wrong' });
            }
        })
        setLoading(false);
        return;
    }
```

2. The user submits his verification code:

```js
    const generateRandomPassword = () => {
        const randexp = new RandExp(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$/);
        return randexp.gen();
    }

    const handleVarificationCodeSubmit = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        // code comes from a setState
        cognitoUser.confirmPassword(code.join(''), generateRandomPassword(), {
            onSuccess: (_data) => {
                setStep(2);
            },
            onFailure: (err) => {
                console.log(err)
                alert('Wrong Code');
            },
        });
        setLoading(false);
    }
```

3. The user chooses a new password:

```js
    const handlePasswordsSubmit = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setFormDataErrors({});
        const { password, confirmPassword } = formData; // this is the form state
        const errors = {};
        if(!password) {
            _.set(errors, 'password', 'Password is required')
        }
        if(!confirmPassword) {
            _.set(errors, 'confirmPassword', 'Confirm Password is required')
        }
        if(!_.isEmpty(errors)) {
            setFormDataErrors(errors);
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }
        const passwordRegex: RegExp = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$/;
        const isValidPassword: boolean = passwordRegex.test(_.get(formData, 'password', ''));
        if(!isValidPassword) {
            setFormDataErrors({ password: 'Must contain at least 8 characters, 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase letter and 1 number' });
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }
        if(_.get(formData, 'password') !== _.get(formData, 'confirmPassword')) {
            setFormDataErrors({ confirmPassword: 'Passwords don\'t match' });
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }
        cognitoUser.confirmPassword(code.join(''), _.get(formData, 'password'), {
            onSuccess: (_data) => {
                setStep(3);
            },
            onFailure: (_err) => {
                console.log(_err)
                setFormDataErrors({ password: 'Something went wrong' });
            }
        });

        setLoading(false);
    }
```

I've tried this flow but it does not work, I am getting an error demanding that the code is incorrect (probably because I already used it when I generated a random password).

```
ExpiredCodeException: Invalid code provided, please request a code again.
```

I could not find any other way to go about it. Is there a way to achieve what I desire?

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:
I've tried switching the password change in step 3 to this:

```js
        const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
        const params = {
            Password: _.get(formData, 'password'),
            Permanent: true,
            UserPoolId: userpool.getUserPoolId(),
            Username: _.get(formData, 'email', ''),
        };

        try{
            await cognito.adminSetUserPassword(params, (_data, err) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                    setFormDataErrors({ password: 'Something went wrong' });
                }
            }).promise();
        } catch(e){
            console.log(e)
            setFormDataErrors({ password: 'Something went wrong' });
        }
```

But, alas, I am getting the follow error:

```
InvalidSignatureException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```